# Gnu Screen asks for password when I close a screen: what password does it want?

Tags: macos, bash, terminal, osx-yosemite, gnu-screen

I have multiple screens running the same long process.

When I **try to close one** (C-a, x), I get a blank screen with:

```
Key:    •
```

When I **type anything and press return**, I get:

```
Again:  •
```

If it's different, I get "Passwords don't match" and **if it's the same** I get:

```
Screen used by Andrew Swift <local>.
Password:•
```

My **administrator password** doesn't work.

**How can I close the screen correctly?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `CTRL-A x` - mean "lock the screen".

So, it asking you for the locking password (of course twice). You can enter any string. Of course, when they did't matches it says mischmah.

After you locked the screen session, you need enter the password again for unlock the session. Simply enter the chosed password again.

Instead of locking, you can "detach the screen" session (CTRL-A D) or you simply use CTRL-D for ending the running shell..

Comment: Had the same issue. To close/remove a split region it's capital X meaning we actually have to do `ctrl-a shift-x`. Doing this in GCP and I'm stuck with screen asking me for a password, had to reset the machine. :-\

Comment: You can see my answer here to disable this annoying feature https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/768248/111873

Answer (score 1):

C-a x is the default combination for "lock screen", not "close". It's asking for a password twice to *set* that password, so that you have to type it again to get back in.

The normal way to close a screen window is to exit the shell at its root, usually by typing `exit`. Pressing C-d (which sends an EOF character) may also work, depending on the shell.

I just came upon this "cheatsheet", which summarises the various commands quite well: http://aperiodic.net/screen/quick_reference

Comment: The idea of locking is to secure the terminal. But if I kill the terminal window and then reattach in a new one (`screen -RD`), I can enter the screen sessions without being asked for passwd. Is there a way to be asked for password upon reattaching?
[UPDATE]: found answer [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/197813/66897)